# Debugging bootstrap-table and extensions unminified or with source maps

Tags: npm, laravel-mix, bootstrap-table

1. I install bootstrap-table and some of its extensions via npm
2. I load it via:

```
require('bootstrap-table');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-de-DE.js');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js');
require('bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.min.js');
```

I would like to use browser developer tools and debug into the internals of this library to better understand it.

- However, currently I use the minified-versions of the distributables. What do I need to change in order to get readable sources in my browser of that library?

  - if I simply use the non-minified versions of the distributables, it's still unreadable since it is compiled.
- I don't think there are sourcemaps available
- do I need to build it locally, if so how?